# Account and/or Balance not found in Geth for Smart Contract Deployment

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, contract-deployment, balances

### Error

> 'Error: Account does not exist or account balance too low'

## Overview

I'm trying to deploy the greeter smart contract in the [ethereum.org/greeter](https://www.ethereum.org/greeter) tutorial.
I downloaded/validated the blockchain history. Etherscan shows there's 0.05 ETH in my account but when I check the balance in geth console using the steps below it says 0 ETH.

**Account** with .05 ETH https://etherscan.io/address/0xf074d2b114e8c15e19503288f4ce5fd641bc0fdd
**Transaction** 0xeebffdaceef818dcc37d59757d707cc7ddc3d1f9cb84965842f1fdb6c379638e
**Block** 4058263

### Terminal1:

Show that my account in my ethereum geth node doesn't have a balance:

> geth --rpc --rpcaddr "127.0.0.1" --rpcport "8545" --fast --cache=2048 console
>   > personal.unlockAccount("f074d2b114e8c15e19503288f4ce5fd641bc0fdd", "my_password")
>   true
>   > web3.eth.getBalance("f074d2b114e8c15e19503288f4ce5fd641bc0fdd");
>   0

But the array that this command outputs contains my transaction

> > web3.eth.getBlock(4058263).transactions
>   [huge array of transactions, including 0xeebffdaceef818dcc37d59757d707cc7ddc3d1f9cb84965842f1fdb6c379638e]

So my local history shows that this transaction took place right? I wonder why the account balance isn't updated when I run the above commands. Its almost as if I need an account update command (I found one but its only for resetting password) that says, "Check the history to see if anyone sent me ether".

### Terminal2:

```
node myFirstSolidityContract.js
```

> Error: Account does not exist or account balance too low
>      at Object.InvalidResponse (/Users/WillsHome/Projects/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:38:16)
>      at /Users/WillsHome/Projects/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:86:36
>      at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/Users/WillsHome/Projects/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:118:13)
>      at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/Users/WillsHome/Projects/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:18)
>      at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/Users/WillsHome/Projects/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:12)
>      at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/Users/WillsHome/Projects/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:509:12)
>      at IncomingMessage. (/Users/WillsHome/Projects/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:469:24)
>      at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
>      at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
>      at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)

### myFirstSolidityContract.js Code

```
var Web3 = require('web3')
web3 = new Web3();
web3.setProvider(new 
web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));  
var solc = require('solc');  

var greeterSource = 'contract mortal { address owner; function mortal()
{  
 owner = msg.sender; } function kill() { if (msg.sender == owner)  
 selfdestruct(owner); } } contract greeter is mortal { string greeting;  

 function greeter(string _greeting) public { greeting = _greeting; }  
 function greet() constant returns (string) { return greeting; } 
}'  

console.log('\n ===== my account ========', web3.eth.accounts[3])
// f074d2b114e8c15e19503288f4ce5fd641bc0fdd

var greeterCompiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(greeterSource)
var _greeting = "Hello World!"
var greeterContract = 
web3.eth.contract(greeterCompiled.greeter.info.abiDefinition);

console.log('\n ====== going to deploy ======') // last thing that logs

// throws error 'Account does not exist or account balance too low'
var greeter = greeterContract.new(_greeting,{from:web3.eth.accounts[3], 
data: greeterCompiled.greeter.code, gas: 300000}, function(e, contract)
{
console.log('\n ==== deployed? ====') // does not log
if(!e) {

  if(!contract.address) {
    console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " + contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined...");

  } else {
    console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address);
    console.log(contract);
  }

} else {
  console.log('\n ====== error ====== \n', e)
}
})
```

Comment: I'd suggest to make your test first in testnet for example https://www.rinkeby.io.